# How to display text when button clicked?

Tags: java, swing

New to using jswing just wondering how to make a button that has some calculation to display a text on a label? Like 3 buttons that holds 3 different value and then have a Calculate button that displays the result to a label?

```
JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Single");
    rdbtnNewRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TotalPay = TotalPay + Single;
        }

JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("Two or more");
    rdbtnNewRadioButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TotalPay = TotalPay + two;
        }
    });

JRadioButton rdbtnWithPet = new JRadioButton("With Pet");
    rdbtnWithPet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TotalPay = TotalPay + Pet;
        }
    });

 JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //What code to insert to display label result?  
        }
    });

 JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel(""); //result of the total must display here?
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(232, 47, 110, 69);
    frmPaulasPortraits.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
```

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: You shouldn't calculate totalPay until you get in the action listener of the calculate button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What code to insert to display label result?

**1.** Insert this one:

```
lblNewLabel_2.setText(String.valueOf(TotalPay));
```

**2.** Initialize your `lblNewLabel_2` before the `btnNewButton` and make it `final`:

```
final JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
```

**3.** Do not use `setBounds` method for `JLabel` directly. `LayoutManager` will do that for you

**4.** There is a lot of tutorials for `Swing`, *use the Force, Luke!*

Answer (score 3):

1. Variable name in Java should not start with capital letter.
2. Always post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) : instead of a code snippets, which doesn't really reflect whatever you are doing
3. Declared all of your using component in the class context instead of inside of a function, as it the declared component instance's will be local to function and we might face trouble working with anonymous class and it's function. So declare `lblNewLabel_2` to your class context
4. As all of the `RadioButton` in your context does the same task: updaing the label's text content with some particular variable try using one instance of `ActionLisnter`. To do so, implement it to some class `MyActionLister implements ActionListener` and implement the `actionPerformed` function. More discussion about the design sense is off-topic as your question currently stays.

However to set `text` on each radio button's action event, you will need to do something like following:

```
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TotalPay = TotalPay + Pet;
            lblNewLabel_2.setText(""+TotalPay);
        }
```

Comment: wow, you have the same amount of notes for this question :)

Comment: aaaaaaaaah, i have missed more points. `setBound`. I will give you +1 for that :)

Comment: your answer is informative, take your points, buddy ;)